# Finding the equation of a plane in 3-D by using point-to-point distances

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

Assume that we have a plane $P(a,b,c,d)$ whose equation is unknown.
We know that there is a point set $N = \{n_1, n_2, ...\}$ and $\forall n_i \in N$, $n_i$ is on $P$.
Also, $\forall n_i, n_j \in N$, we know the euclidian distance between $n_i$ and $n_j$.

Now, let us assume we have another point set $M = \{m_1, m_2, ...\}$ and $\forall m_i \in M$, we know the coordinates of $m_i$.

How many pairwise distances $d(n_i,m_j)$ do we need to find the equation of $P$ and the most important part; **how do we calculate it?**

I'm going to write a Java code for this, so please help me to solve this problem step by step.

Here is what I have acheived so far:

A plane has 3 unknowns: $a,b,c,d$ I need a linear system that has 4 equations.
Assume that we have 4 point-to-point connections.
Namely: $(n_1, m_1)$, $(n_2, m_2)$, $(n_3, m_3)$ and $(n_4, m_4)$
Knowns:

- $d(n_1, m_1)$
- $d(n_2, m_2)$
- $d(n_3, m_3)$
- $d(n_4, m_4)$
- $d(n_1, n_2)$
- $d(n_1, n_2)$
- $d(n_1, n_3)$
- $d(n_1, n_4)$
- $d(n_2, n_3)$
- $d(n_2, n_4)$
- $d(n_3, n_4)$
- $coplanar(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4)$
- $x,y,z$ coordinates of $m_1$
- $x,y,z$ coordinates of $m_2$
- $x,y,z$ coordinates of $m_3$
- $x,y,z$ coordinates of $m_4$

Unknowns:

- a
- b
- c
- d

That seems easy, but I could not build a linear system.

**Important notice:** Because of quadratic equations, there might be two solutions. Two solutions are OK. But in some cases, there are infinitely many solutions.
The question may be asked: What are the characteristics of the distance measurements $d(m_i, n_j)$ to localize $P$?

Comment: If you already have points $M$ on $P_2$, then don't you already know the equation of that plane?

Comment: I only know the number of points and their relative poisitons on the plane. Since I don't know the equation of the planes, I don't know the coordinates of the points.

Comment: What do you mean relative positions on the plane? So you know the pair-wise difference vectors $m_2-m_1$, etc.? That does not fix the positions globally, but it is enough to compute the normal vector of the plane.

Comment: @VictorLiu I mean, if you assume that plane is $z = 0$ plane, all the coordinates are known.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that you mean you only know the $x,y$ coordinates, and not $z$? And your plane is restricted to be a graph in the $x,y$ plane?

Comment: I find the question very unclear. If you only know the distances, you cannot distinguish between translated configurations in parallel planes.

Comment: You can when you have distance measurents with known points.

Comment: Assume the $m_i$ coplanar and all $d(m_i,n_i)=1$. Then there are at least two solutions. What I'm saying is that the problem is highly nonlinear, and there might be many different planes $P$ satisfying the conditions.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter you are completely right. In this case, there are infinitely many solutions. However, what if $d(m_i, n_j) \neq d(m_k, l_k)$? What would be the characteristics? How can I detect if there is a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every known distance corresponds to a rod, you need $M\ge3$, otherwise the system is a mechanism (you can rotate it around $m_1m_2$).

Knowing three $m$ points allows you to directly obtain the absolute position of any point $n$ by solving a system of 3 quadratic equations in 3 unknowns. You will find two solutions, symmetric wrt the plane $m_1m_2m_3$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration

From 9 $d(m_i,n_j)$ distances, you can retrieve 3 $n_j$ points and construct the plane. You can reject some of the solutions (among $2^3=8$ combinations) by checking compatibility with the $d(n_j,n_k)$ distances. But this deserves deeper analysis.

Using a fourth $m_4$ point not coplanar with the other three shoud allow you to always resolve ambiguity.

If computing the $d(m_i,n_j)$ is more "costly" than the $d(n_j,n_k)$, you can do with less evaluations by constructing $n_1$ from $m_1, m_2, m_3$, then $n_2$ from $n_1, m_2, m_3$ and $n_3$ from $n_1, n_2, m_3$.